# If $G$ is an abelian group then $H= \big\{ x\in G\ | \ x^3=1_G \big\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group. Then the subset $H= \big\{ x\in G\  | \ x^3=1_G \big\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I was able to show the statement is correct but the weird thing is that I didn't use the fact $G$ is abelian. **Is it possible that the fact $G$ is abelian is redundant?**

Here is how I proved the statement above without using the fact $G$ is abelian:

**(Identity)** Of course the identity is in H because $1_G^3=1_G$.

**(Closure)** Suppose $a,b\in H$ then $a^3=1_G$ and $b^3=1_G$. Therefore we have:
$(ab)^3 = a^3b^3 = 1_G1_G = 1_G$.

**(Inverse)** Suppose $a\in H$ then $a^3=1_G \implies aa^2=1_G \implies a^{-1} = a^2$

Am I correct?

Comment: You use that $G$ is commutative when you write $(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$.

Comment: @user133281 Why?

Comment: $(ab)^3 = ababab$, $a^3b^3 = aaabbb$. These are not a priori the same.

Comment: @user133281 Correct... Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that $G$ is abelian for the step $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$.

In general, $H$ does not need to be a subgroup of $G$. For instance, consider $G = S_4$. Then the product of $(123)$, $(124) \in H$ is not in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

For the inverse you should prove that if $a\in H$ then $a^{-1}$ is also in $H$. Notice that there's an alternative proof: it suffices to show that

$$\varphi: G\to G,\quad x\mapsto x^3$$
is a group's morphism and remark that $H=\ker\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now see that my last step where I tried to prove the inverse is incorrect.

Comment: You're welcome.